# Word classes "which is why"

Tags: word-classes, clauses

What are the word classes of the adverbial "[...] which is why [...]"?
is cannot be a lexical verb, can it? 
I thought which is a relative pronoun, and why is an adverb of reason.

Comment: Traditional Word-class/POS lore won't get you very far with this and the other 'interrogatives'. It's sometimes called a 'relative adverb', which is pretty far-fetched, since it's neither relative nor an adverb. How 'bout "nominalizer"?

Answer (score 1):

The question becomes clearer if a concrete example is given, e.g.

(1) They laughed at me, which is why I left.

Yes, the *which* here is a relative pronoun. The unique thing about it is that it takes the entire matrix clause as its antecedent -- most relative pronouns have just a noun as (part of) their antecedent. And yes, the wh-word *why* is an interrogatve adverb; in this case, it functions as a predicative expression, similar to how a predicative adjective or noun functions. Given these considerations, there is nothing particularly challenging about the formulation.

The answer to the question is therefore that the expression *...which is why...* is not a single unit, but rather it is compositional, made up of smaller parts that one can identify and combine productively.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster lists *how* and *why* as adverbs. But in several cases, they appear to take a role that mirrors that of the pronoun *what*, as a noun phrase head introducing a relative clause. Compare these examples that illustrate how *how* and *why* fill the noun-like role commonly associated with a pronoun:

- "...which is why we do it"
- "This is why we do it"
- "This is how we do it"
- "This is what we do *[t]*" (where *[t]* is a [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linguistics%29))
- "How you're doing it is not how you're supposed to do it"
- "Why you did it doesn't matter"
- "I'm telling you why it's a pronoun"

Here, *what* means "the thing that", *why* means "the reason that", and *how* means "the way that".